# ¿Sería conveniente usar un Store Procedure para realizar dos insert en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, stored-procedure

Mi duda viene por lo siguiente:

estoy tratando de hacer un insert en dos tablas que están relacionadas, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```js
const insert = ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email } ) => {
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  //console.log('VALOR DE ACTIVE: ',active);
  //date = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
  //date2 = moment().add(3,'d').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); 
  //console.log(`Fecha 1: ${date} Fecha 2: ${date2}`);
  bd.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], (err,rows)=>{
   const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
   const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(name+userId,salt); 
   console.log('EJECUTANDO EL OTRO INSERTTT: '+rows.insertId)
   bd.query('INSERT INTO cuenta (activa,hash_activacio,id_usuario) VALUES (?,?,?)', ['0',hash,rows.insertId], (err,rows)=>{
    //return (err)? reject(err): resolve(rows);
   } )
   return (err)? reject(err): resolve(rows);
  }); 
 });
};
```

anteriormente tenía el primer insert solamente y funcionaba bien, si había algún error me lo mostraba al resolver la promesa, pero tuve que modificar la BD y ahora tengo que hacer un segundo insert y quiero hacerlo en esa misma función. El problema que se me presentó es que estoy notando que si hay un error al ejecutar el segundo insert éste no se me muestra, por ejemplo, si escribo mal una columna, la inserción no se hace, pero tampoco me retorna un error y esto me hace pensar que hay algo mal en mi código, pero no se de que otra forma se podría hacer y que sea de la manera correcta.

Investigando encontré esto, y cito: "Siempre que necesites realizar alguna operación con tu Base de Datos (inserción, actualización, borrado, consulta) DEBES SÍ O SÍ usar un stored procedure." Acá está en el link de dónde extraje esa cita:  https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sistemas-gestores-de-bases-de-datos/0-AO9ss5SO4 .Entonces, esto me generó aún más dudas, también leí que los store procedure no se deberían usar para la lógica de negocios (aquí tampoco estoy muy claro), así que quisiera las opiniones de alguien con experiencia en esto.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar con esto. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes añadir referencias para las citas que pones en la pregunta? Sería bueno para ver el contexto. Aparte, deberías considerar "reformular" la pregunta un poco, tal y como está escrita parece más basada en opiniones que pidiendo referencia objetiva sobre el tema. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Hola!, sumando a lo que comenta @AlvaroMontoro, puedes cambiar la pregunta por algo como qué beneficios proporciona usar un stored procedure vs la ejecución del query directo. Dicho eso, lo que leiste es más un patrón que se solía usar pero ya no se ve mucho, en tu caso me parece que podrías trabajar con transacciones y resolverías ese problema.

Comment: Lo que comento de la cita lo saqué de acá, estaba buscando información y leí esto: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sistemas-gestores-de-bases-de-datos/0-AO9ss5SO4

Comment: El problema surgió como comenté en mi pregunta fue al incorporar el segundo insert, cuando solo tenía uno solo no se me complicaba, lo que quiero es hacer el segundo insert en esa misma función. Bien podría crear otra función que me retorne otra promesa pero pienso que se podría hacer dentro de esa misma función, además de que son operaciones similares y que que se ejecutan juntas prácticamente.

Comment: Entonces vuelvo a mi consejo, necesitas es crear una transacción, la idea de la misam es que se realicen todas las operaciones y si falla alguna se hace un rollback de los cambios, dicho de otra manera si no se cumplen todas las operaciones no se aplican los cambios. Sería algo como iniciar transaccion, query 1, query 2, commit, fin de transacción. De donde sale ese DB? una librería a ver si encuentro como se hace con esa

Comment: Es una BD de MySql, y estoy trabajando con expréss de Nodejs en el back y angular en el front. Estoy leyendo sobre las transacciones, es parecido a un Store Procedure a mi parecer, aunque veo es como se ejecuta directamente en MySql, eso iría en la BD como tal o en el código del backend ? Estoy algo perdido, sinceramente esto es nuevo para mí.

Comment: Iría en el backend en el node.js, no hay necesidad de crear un stored procedure en tu caso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108477/discussion-between-julianprog-and-zerocool).

Comment: Lo siento ya acá son las 3:00 am :D me voy a dormir te dejo en la respuesta cómo sería con tu código más o menos es la idea, esperoque puedas resolver un saludos y suerte :D!!

Comment: Ok, lo revisaré para ver si entiendo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @BetaM Disculpa, ya lo hice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indicas en las etiquetas que trabajas con node.js te dejo una respuesta del sitio de stackoverflow en inglés:

[Transaction Management in nodejs with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529231/transaction-management-in-nodejs-with-mysql)

Explican que node.js tiene implementado el manejo de transacciones así que puedes implementar:

1. Crear la conexión
2. Conectarte a la base de datos
3. Comenzar la transacción usando beginTransaction
4. Ejecutar los querys
5. Si alguno falla usar la función rollback que abortará la transacción
6. Si todo sale bien usar commit (aplica los cambios)
7. Cerrar la conexión usando end

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'YOUR_HOST',
      user     : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
      password : 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
      database : 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
    }
);

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

/* Begin transaction */
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  connection.query('YOUR QUERY', "PLACE HOLDER VALUES", function(err, result) {
    if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }

    const log = result.insertId;

    connection.query('ANOTHER QUERY PART OF TRANSACTION', log, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        connection.rollback(function() {
          throw err;
        });
      }  
      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) { 
          connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        console.log('Transaction Completed Successfully.');
        connection.end();
      });
    });
  });
});
/* End transaction */
```

En tu caso sería algo:

```
const insert = ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email } ) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        //console.log('VALOR DE ACTIVE: ',active);
        //date = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
        //date2 = moment().add(3,'d').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); 
        //console.log(`Fecha 1: ${date} Fecha 2: ${date2}`);
        db.beginTransaction(function(err) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      db.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], function(err, result) {
        if (err) { 
          db.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }

        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(name+userId,salt); 
                console.log('EJECUTANDO EL OTRO INSERTTT: '+rows.insertId)
        db.query('INSERT INTO cuenta (activa,hash_activacio,id_usuario) VALUES (?,?,?)', ['0',hash,rows.insertId], log, function(err, result) {
          if (err) { 
            connection.rollback(function() {
              throw err;
            });
          }  
          db.commit(function(err) {
            if (err) { 
              db.rollback(function() {
                throw err;
              });
            }
            console.log('Transaction Completed Successfully.');
            db.end();
          });
        });
      });
    });

    });
};
```

Comment: Ok, pero tendría que dejar de trabajar con promesas para poder usar las transacciones ? Sinceramente empecé a usar promesas por el tutorial que estaba usando y me costó entenderlas.

Comment: Edito para que veas cómo quedaría con tu código

Comment: Edité de nuevo, no se que hice que deje todo mal, ahora si!. saludos!!

Comment: Hola @zerocool , gracias por el código, le hice unas modificaciones, hice unas pruebas y al parecer está funcionando bien, puedes verlo en una de las respuestas. Me dí cuenta de que al hacer un rollback los campos auto_increment no se reestablecen, me puse a leer y al parecer esto es normal y no hay forma de resolverse, creo que no afectaría en nada en un futuro o si?

Comment: Hola, el tema con los incrementales es que eso nace de una secuencia en la base de datos, cada vez que se intenta hacer un insert se pregunta a la secuencia cual es el siguiente valor, esa operación modifica la secuencia quedando con el último valor que respondió. Por ello es que no se puede volver a atrás, sin embargo es un comportamiento normal y esperado, y no te va a dar problemas de inserción ya que no volverá a tener un número menor al actual jamas (a menos que la mandes a resetear directamente) :D saludos!.

Comment: Acabo de aceptar tu respuesta. Disculpa, tendrás un tiempo para hacerte unas preguntas en el chat ? Si no es mucha molestia, claro.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108524/discussion-between-zerocool-and-julianprog).

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo para dejar acá la solución que funcióno con ayuda de las personas que me apoyaron en esta pregunta:

```js
const insert = ( {user, name, lastName, pass, email } ) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        //console.log('VALOR DE ACTIVE: ',active);
        //date = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
        //date2 = moment().add(3,'d').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); 
        //console.log(`Fecha 1: ${date} Fecha 2: ${date2}`);
     bd.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

        connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
       if (err) { throw err; }
      connection.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombre,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) { 
          console.log('\n ERORR en el primer insert: \n' +err)
    connection.rollback(function() {
     console.log('\n Ejecutando Rollback 1 \n ')
            return reject(err)
            throw err;
          });
        }

        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(name+userId,salt); 
        console.log('EJECUTANDO EL OTRO INSERTTT: '+rows.insertId)
        connection.query('INSERT INTO cuenta (activa,hash_activacion,id_usuario) VALUES (?,?,?)', ['0',hash,rows.insertId], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) { 
         console.log('\n ERORR en el segundo insert \n ')
            connection.rollback(function() {
    console.log('\n Ejecutando Rollback 2 \n ')
    return reject(err);
               throw err;
            });
          }  
          connection.commit(function(err) {
            if (err) { 
             connection.rollback(function() {
                 return reject(err);
                 throw err;
              });
            }
            console.log('Transaction Completed Successfully.');
            connection.release();
            return resolve(rows)
          });
        });
      });
    });
    });
    });
}
```